# Parsing nested JSON with AlamofireObjectMapper

Tags: swift, alamofire, object-object-mapping

How can I do the Nested JSON data parsing with alamofire?
Actually I need to display all of this in my table view.

- post - id
- post - tittle
- post - content
- post - date
- post - categories - id
- post - categories - title
- post - attachments - url

This is my JSON API:

```
    {
      "status": "ok",
      "posts": [
       { 
        "id": 770,
        "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "content": "Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.",
        "date": "2019-02-19 06:43:33",
        "categories": [
        {
        "id": 156,
        "title": "News"
        }
        ],
        "attachments": [
        {
        "url": "https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/image.jpg"
        }
        ]
       },
       {22 items},
       {22 items},
       {22 items}
       ]
    }
```

Actually I need to display all of this in my table view.
 - post - id
 - post - tittle
 - post - content
 - post - date
 - post - categories - id
 - post - categories - title
 - post - attachments - url

This is my code. i don't know whether it is correct not.

```
  import UIKit
  import ObjectMapper
  import AlamofireObjectMapper
  import Alamofire

  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{     
    @IBOutlet weak var tableOut: UITableView!

    var posts = [Post]()
    let urlString = "https://website.com/api/get_recent_posts/"

    //Model class for Post
    class Post: Mappable {
        var postContent: [Subpost]?

        required init?(map: Map) {}

        // Mappable
        func mapping(map: Map) {
            postContent <- map["posts"]
            //print(postContent!) : its not working..... getting null value.
        }
    }

    class Subpost:Mappable{
        var title:String?
        var slug:String?

        required init?(map: Map) {}

        func mapping(map: Map) {
            title <- map["title"]
            slug <- map["slug"]
            //print(title!)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<Post>) in
            //print("Response: \(response)")
            print(response.result.value as Any)
            if let blog = response.result.value{
                //self.posts.append(contentsOf: blog)
                self.tableOut.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellObj = tableOut.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        //cellObj.titleOut.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
       // cellObj.slugOut.text = posts[indexPath.row].slug
        return cellObj
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

}
```

**TableViewCell.swift**

- @IBOutlet weak var slugOut: UILabel!
- @IBOutlet weak var titleOut: UILabel!
- @IBOutlet weak var contentOut: UILabel!
- @IBOutlet weak var imageOut: UIImageView! etc

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Does it do what you want or not?

Comment: I'm getting this in the debugger area
`[TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost, TheCityApp.ViewController.Subpost]
TheCityApp.ViewController.Post`